# Android: how to support both user orientation and the one that is manually requested from activity

Tags: android

I have specified the `screenOrientation` in manifest to `user`. I have a button in my activity and whenever a user clicks the button, I request the orientation change: portrait to landscape and vice versa. The problem is that after I request the orientation using:

```
requireActivity().requestedOrientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
```

the activity stops sending the configuration changes events, since the orientation is not `user` anymore. Is there any way I can both listen for orientation changes and manually request orientation change?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Solution ;-

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        }
        else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }
```

Comment: I already tried it - it does not solve the problem

Comment: are you added screen orientation in manifest for particular activity ?

Comment: Yes, I did specified the orientation to "user"

Comment: Whenever activity call then first in oncreate call setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);          After That in on button check orientation condition.